# Ansible Playbook: Unreachable host continues block

Tags: ansible

I'll explain my scenario verbally to see if I'm attempting to tackle this in the wrong way:

**Scenario 1: All OK**

1. Task 1 always runs for all hosts
2. "Ensure Apache is started" is attempted
3. If "Ensure Apache is started" is successful, "Wait for website..." executes
4. If "Wait for website..." is successful, everything is OK. `rescue` block does not execute

**Scenario 2: Website Fails**

1. Task 1 always runs for all hosts
2. "Ensure Apache is started" is attempted
3. If "Ensure Apache is started" is successful, "Wait for website..." executes
4. If "Wait for website..." fails, `rescue` block executes

I believe the above 2 are covered by Ansible as-is - that is the default behaviour of the `block / rescue` construct.

**Scenario 3 - Host unreachable**

1. Task 1 always runs for all hosts
2. "Ensure Apache is started" is attempted
3. "Ensure Apache is started" is unsuccessful because the host cannot be reached (via SSH)
4. "Wait for website" does not execute. The playbook does not fail. The `rescue` block is executed.

It is this third scenario that I'm struggling with. An unreachable host seems to fail the playbook. I've tried `ignore_unreachable` but then the task seems successful and so the `rescue` block isn't executed. It seems I want the best of both worlds.

```
tasks:
  - name: "Task 1"
  ...

  - name: "Start Apache"
    block:
    - name: "Ensure Apache is started"
      ansible.builtin.service:
          name: apache2
          state: started

    - name: "Wait for website to come up on this host"
      delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
      uri:
        url: "http://{{inventory_hostname}}"
        return_content: yes
      register: _result
      until: _result.content != '\"\"'
      retries: 5
      delay: 5
  
    rescue:
    - name: "Do Something"
      ...
```

Comment: I believe connection errors are not covered with 'rescue' block.